# Yum command is not working in fedora, when i removed the libacl package?

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, yum

During updating fedora, due to `error: multilib protected version found`, i tried to remove and install `libacl` package, but when i remove `libacl` package using `rpm --erase --nodeps libacl`, yum commands stops working and i am unable to install libacl again , running yum gives this error:-

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libacl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.5 (default, Nov 12 2013, 16:18:42) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131017 (Red Hat 4.8.2-1)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

Not only yum but when i fire any command in the terminal it gives this error:-

```
error while loading shared libraries: libacl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Due to this I am not able to install any package manually using rpm command, Someone please give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Manually download `libacl` RPM and do `rpm2cpio packagefile.rpm | cpio -div` and then manually copy `libacl.so.1` to where it should be. Then install the RPM properly. After that, don't use `--nodeps` again, unless you're *sure* you know what you're doing! ;)